# Make my button type="submit" open another accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

On my website which is using Bootstrap3 and I have a page which has 3 accordions on. All the accordions have fields and buttons and each has there own process in them.

The issue I have is that when I click my `<button type="submit">` from accordion 1, I want it to open accordion 2 (for example).  The button has to fire in my code behind so that it terminate the process done in accordion 1 before opening accordion 2. Obviously I cant use `<button type="button">` as this doesn't fire in the code behind and I styled a `<a>` but then realized I couldn't get this to fire in the code behind.

One solution I was given was to add `href` to the button although this isn't supported as it removes everything from my accordions so what other ways can I direct my button to fire in code behind to end my process and then open accordion 2.

Maybe it needs to be done in JavaScript/jQuery or directly in HTML I don't know.  I would prefer HTML but I'm open to all suggestions please.

I Googled it and I know that for a `button type="button"` the following attributes are required `data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="NameOfMyParent"`

Comment: Yes, you'd need to use some JQuery and AJAX for submitting your form and some simple javascript/JQuery for accordian toggles - Although this part can be done with HTML5 as well.

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle?

Comment: @AnudeepRentala Could you please provide something I could work off then. The button will also need the following attributes for it to work according to Google but I only found these for a `button type="button"` `data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="NameOfMyParent"`

Comment: You could use those on attributes and still achieve what you want to. Refer to the answer by @Asenar. You basically follows those instructions and attach a click event handler to your button like : $("#yourButtonID").on("click", function(e){ //your ajax call  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed. All i needed to do was add an `id` to the `panel-body` and then reference it in my button using `data-target`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to use javascript (as you already do it with the accordion). I assume you use jquery (as you use Bootstrap). So a solution, is to bind an event to prevent the submit (on form submit or on button click), and submit the form with `$.ajax()` (this can be complex if your form contains some upload process).

```
$("#your_form_id").on("submit", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var url = $(this).action;
  var data = {};
  /* get your form datas here */
  $.ajax({
    url:url,
    data:data,
    /* use any of theses callback, or none 
     *if you don't care about the request is correct or not
     */
    success:function(res){},
    error:function(res){},
    complete:function(res){
       // call your second accordion here
    }
  })
});
```

Alternatively, you can use a `<input type="button">` and do the opposite work: bind an event to it to fire the submit, or just start the accordion, or anything.